# displaying the value of the p:dataTable cell on click event of the p:panelGrid using p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable, panelgrid

I have p:dataTable, inside column I have a panelGrid where i want the value of the ouputText on the click of the panelGrid without page refresh. The code is something like:

```
<p:column headerText="5/5" style="width:40px; font-size:9pt;">  
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.showSelectedValue(row)}" update=":mainForm"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.value1}" />  
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
<h:panelGrid id="ForecastChartTab"> 
    <h:outputText id="value1" value="#{myBean.showValue.value1}" />  
</h:panelGrid>
```

This is working, but the value is seen only on page refresh...! is something  wrong here? :(

Comment: #Preeti Singh what you want to do exactly, your question is not clear

Comment: I want the value without page refresh. ajax call should work with out having the page refresh

Comment: you want to refresh your mainForm when you click at panelGrid? or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the table, you can use the following

```
update="@([id$=dtTableId])"
```

If you need to update the output text you need use the following

```
update="@([id$= value1])"
```

With this type of format `@([id$= value1])`, you can update another component out of the behavior of others.